# How to validate data in Teradata from Oracle

Tags: teradata

My source data is in Oracle and target data is in Teradata.Can you please provide me the easy and quick way to validate data .There are 900 tables.If possible can you provide syntax too

Answer (score 0):

There is a product available known as the Teradata Gateway that works with Oracle and allows you to access Teradata in a "heterogeneous" manner. This may not be the most effective way to compare the data.

Ultimately what your requirements sound more process driven and to be done effectively would require the source data to be compared/validated as stage tables on the Teradata environment after your ETL/ELT process has completed.